# How can I add a discount to the cart total in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add some additional discounts to the cart total and I tried this code but it's not quite working for me.

```
function mysite_box_discount( ) {

global $woocommerce;

$total_disc = 10;

  // Alter the cart discount total
  $woocommerce->cart->discount_total = $total_disc;

}
add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'mysite_box_discount');
```

I also tried adding `$cart` as an argument to the function, but it didn't work.
I also tried `$cart->discount_total` but it is not working for me either.

Comment: Yes Loic those answers are neat but I'll tell you what the actual requirement is..Client wants that on the cart page ( or checkout page ) we ask the customer if he will like to have delayed shipping , if he says yes then we give him 5% discount and similarly some 2-3 more items, so more like a checkbox group in any of those 2 pages and then the total bill to be varied accordingly.. any suggestions

Comment: Thank you in advance Loic .. I hope and wish  I have a working solution in the next 24 hours..

Comment: With woocommerce everything is possible (for small/medium web shops)… Staying in touch:)

Comment: I know that when it comes to coding almost everything is possible ( if not everything ) but then when there is a code as big as woocommerce is , it surely can be challenging and time consuming if you have never gone through the code before , but with people like you willing to assist and having the expertise on woocommerce I think we can have a working solution sooner than if I was to bang my head on it alone..Staying in touch with you .. DEFINITELY YES because you have saved me a lot of times already..

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
function custom_wc_add_discount() {
    $total_disc = 10;
    WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Discount note', -$total_disc );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_wc_add_discount' );
```

Comment: Thanks buddy .. I now have a discount note , I will now have to get the discount checkboxes and then link it to this function..I will try and get the rest on my own and If I am stuck I will ask you again..